# Pandas DataFrame to Numpy Array ValueError

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am trying to convert a single column of a dataframe to a numpy array. Converting the entire dataframe has no issues.

df

```
  viz  a1_count  a1_mean     a1_std
0   0         3        2   0.816497
1   1         0      NaN        NaN 
2   0         2       51  50.000000
```

Both of these functions work fine:

```
X = df.as_matrix()
X = df.as_matrix(columns=df.columns[1:])
```

However, when I try:

```
y = df.as_matrix(columns=df.columns[0])
```

I get:

```
TypeError: Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind, 'viz' was passed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you're passing just a single element which in this case is just the string title of that column, if you convert this to a list with a single element then it works:

```
In [97]:
y = df.as_matrix(columns=[df.columns[0]])
y

Out[97]:
array([[0],
       [1],
       [0]], dtype=int64)
```

Here is what you're passing:

```
In [101]:
df.columns[0]

Out[101]:
'viz'
```

So it's equivalent to this:

```
y = df.as_matrix(columns='viz')
```

which results in the same error

The [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.as_matrix.html#pandas.DataFrame.as_matrix) show the expected params:

> DataFrame.as_matrix(columns=None) Convert the frame to its Numpy-array
>   representation.
>
> Parameters:    columns: list, optional, default:None If None, return all
>   columns, otherwise, returns specified columns

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Why did it work for `columns=df.columns[1:]` without encapsulating that in a list?

Comment: Because that returned an array but when it's a single element selection it returned the single object only

Comment: Because `df.columns[1:]` is already a list. Consider: `li = [1,2,3,4] li[1:] -> [2,3,4]`

Answer (score 3):

`as_matrix` expects a `list` for the `columns` keyword and `df.columns[0]` isn't a list. Try 
`df.as_matrix(columns=[df.columns[0]])` instead.

Answer (score -1):

Using the index tolist function works as well

```
df.as_matrix(columns=df.columns[0].tolist())
```

When giving multiple columns, for example, the ten first, then the command

```
df.as_matrix(columns=[df.columns[0:10]])
```

**does not work** as it returns an index. However, using

```
df.as_matrix(columns=df.columns[0:10].tolist())
```

works well.